# How to restrict WifiDirect visibility?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

When I turn on WiFi-direct peer discovery, I want that device should be visible only to those devices which are using same app. That is, I do not want wifi direct peer discovery initiated by my app to be visible to other apps.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it’s possible at all , by enabling the discovery feature , Wi-Fi Direct will be a available to all of devices and you cannot filter that at least before connecting to another device

Comment: It would be nice if you could quote some authentic reference.